Characteristic of a generic point
Let $X$ be a scheme, $x$ be a generic point of a closed irreducible subset of $X$. What does it mean to say that the characteristic of $x$ is 0?
This is probably a well-known terminology, but I'm couldn't find its definition stated anywhere. This phrase appears for instance in statements related to the Ihara's lemma.

I would take that to mean the characteristic of the residue field of $x$. (The stalk $\mathcal{O}{X,x}$ is a local ring and the residue field is the quotient $\mathcal{O}{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_{X,x}$.)

I would take that to mean the characteristic of the residue field of $x$. (The stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a local ring and the residue field is the quotient $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_{X,x}$, where $\mathfrak{m}_{X,x}$ is the unique maximal ideal.)
